# Solution of parabolic PDE system

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

For the following parabolic PDE system, $u(x,t)$ and $v(x,t)$ are functions of independent variables $x$ and $t$, $x\in[a,b]$.

\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
\frac{\partial}{\partial t}u=\frac{\partial^{2}u}{\partial x^{2}}+u^{3}+uv^{2},&& a<x<b,t>0\\
\frac{\partial}{\partial t}v=\frac{\partial^{2}v}{\partial x^{2}}+\frac{2}{u}\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}+2[\frac{1}{u}\frac{\partial^{2}u}{\partial x^{2}}-\frac{1}{u^{2}}(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x})^{2}+u^{2}]v,   && a<x<b,t>0\\
u(x,0)=u_{0}(x)\in C^{\infty}(x),u_{0}(x)>0,v(x,0)=v_{0}(x)\in C^{\infty}(x),  &&a\leq x\leq b\\
u(a,t)=u(b,t),v(a,t)=v(b,t),   &&t\geq0
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

Question 1: Does the system have local existence?

If the system have local existence:

Question 2: If $u(x,t)$ is bounded on an interval $[0,\epsilon)$, then does $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(x,t)$ bounded on $[0,\epsilon)$?

Question 3: If $u(x,t)$ and $v(x,t)$ are bounded on an interval $[0,\epsilon)$, then does $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(x,t)$ bounded on $[0,\epsilon)$?

Question 4: If $u(x,t)$ is bounded on an interval $[0,\epsilon)$, then does $v(x,t)$ bounded on $[0,\epsilon)$?

Comment: Putting $u=e^w$ leads to a quasilinear system on $v$ and  $w$ with smooth coefficients.